# Extract data from text string

Tags: encryption, text, mp3

I've found this string :

``````
M``1@W?!E[G$0C#&/X)A#&<605QS8!W#^A;X"D%CI"D_XGT$"=&L:*_B'JI2K
M<.9H*78G0G+J(*R3KB6A%3A2QU5$@L0?[H0\,45&$K0,X`%'9YC`'L#`JA-`
M_!$&%(!2Q?J+&(EUHB&"OT*7E@DN"#)#.""/7L"Q@=[0;`8^`G]$4]06F4-7
MXOL8011Q*W2`7`Q/TI@EE2'9$=>`$2\8(.`PB@V`JC%``(CM&O.7HA*`,O06
M\.:V(1&!HU.0"_,$9RJ/%COJR*O>ZJAC'R\`J@`!$"6$:3!'0#"YI8/"DR5A
M39?`+H;[BADO4>IWR:+AH95:%!".4BJ@```"*@`````*#@8``)Z_`P`A`"<"
MF(6```-:CJ:U'4AMCPU_UUX2YH'L.<<`*"@K)_`2K:CL;E:QST>62]03H)RG
ME8BCHQC!",MU1<E=_X%2/C1U++5-@(`W*DT_%,7>Z&J8X-)8]`20_85<*$^M
MHL/<^^K;[_`($"YZJMFF^2222GR_!H*+^K)<M:XX50```!L01659A5-V=>[N
M@_`?BMX<!W47_&"%N7HV@S^>EKZXD%^<ZT):F/UT,RL&.N,`8QFZTP4!#=3[
M%]L!.</+>!D2Y'(W[E(^HY"`G56O4&IX0JR7/^(Q]IMAK!K=&?QDNV$FXZNC
M@>'8DGE#>4&_S`'@S2X``\DQ!GH%&@R\]`^MQ6`+F<5;Y>C@?UT("7';^90C
MV!9!165U)R7`!;Y,I>.T%@2ZIRA>9E1P3HYP.*)F5`&J0#+J!+XPT&!R7N^J
MB#K'=#=5>D"BP]V%4``S#&`D/&PN'8",NRAOA1EYMJ4=::C#25!(TBWIQE3=
``````

It's supposed to be mp3 files.

How to make it into the mp3 file,
and what is name of the thing like this?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com (where they will probably tell you that it is uuencoded).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like uuencode'd file. Look into uudecode/uuencode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be uuencoded or a similar encoding.  Most tools should handle the similar encodin automatically.  It should have a header containing the file name.  You may need to add the appropriate header and trailer for the decoder to work.  Encoding a file and the line before the encoded text and the line after the encoded text should work.  Change the file name so you don't risk overwriting the original file.